# How to customize the dynamic table produced by streamlit?

Tags: python, datatable, jquery-ui-sortable, streamlit

I would like to use the dynamic table in Streamlit for data analysis as it has a good feature of sorting tables by clicking on the table header. however, the font size of this table is too small to read and therefore I am looking for the best possible way to customize this table especially font size and text color.

```
Asked 6 days ago
Modified 6 days ago
Viewed 56 times
0

import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st

df = pd.read_csv('data/AUDCAD_1h.csv', index_col=0)

st.dataframe(df, use_container_width=True)
```